# Execute an SQL statement daily at midnight

Tags: task, firebird

I need to program a task so that everyday at midnight an SQL statement like this is executed:

```sql
INSERT INTO DAILY_INVENTORY Values (A.COST, B.COST, C.COST);
```

I have no clue on how to do make it happen automatically everyday, please help!

Comment: Firebase <> Firebird. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm afraid that you can not do this without an external program(service). See : http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-1717 and http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-743

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebird does not have a scheduler. So if you want to execute something at fixed intervals, you need to use an external scheduler (for example `cron` on Linux, or *Task Scheduler* on Windows).

Explaining in detail all possibilities and options would be far too broad.